# Align anchor tags below a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 tables which appear side by side, and I have 2 button related to each of these tables
and I want the button (anchor tags) to appear below the table while the table remains side by side

my table structure is as follows:

```
<div id="table">
<div id="detail-table">
<table>
...some table data...
</table>
<a href></a>
<a href></a>
</div> // detail-table close
<div id="no-detail-table">
<table>
...some table data...
</table>
<a href></a>
<a href></a>
</div> // no-detail-table close
</div> // table div close
```

related CSS:

```
div#table{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

table{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

I want the output to be like this (see image): I tried the float property and position:absolute, top:
, left:!, but couldnt get desired output

[image]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/a8THA/

Comment: Can you provide fiddle demo link here ?

Comment: added jsfiddle link in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `float` to `#table div` and set `width` to `50%`:

```
#table{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#table div {
    width:50%; float:left;
}

table{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/6et4V/)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to declare the tables as block elements (not inline-block) and float the detail divs to achieve the desired effect. For example:

```
table { display:block; }
#detail-table { float:left; }
#no-detail-table { float:left; margin-left: 50px /* Add space between tables. Or you could float this div right (float:right;) */ }
```

Here is a link to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/86NQ7/

Comment: I did what you said but I got links on the right and tables on the left, check my jsfiddle link in OP is has my original table structure

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/geVqV/))

```
#table div {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/geVqV/3/) (Using wrapper div for links)

```
#table div {
    display:inline-block;
}
#table div#links {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

Or, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/geVqV/2/) (using `tfoot`)

```
#table div {
    display:inline-block;
}

div#table table tfoot td{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <a href="some link" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success" download="" id="download-detail-button">Download</a>
          <a class=" btn btn-rounded btn-info" target="_blank" onclick="print command" id="print-button">Print</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/a8THA/2/